# How to click on a webtable cell using UFT/VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I just need to click on a specific cell (2,1). I am not sure how I can click on that cell. In my case, it is always going to be the same cell.

I have this code which just reads the value from cell (2,1). After that, how can I click that cell? Entire cell is a link. I do not need to use for loop to go thru and find value. I just need to click directly on that cell.

```
myvalue= Browser("aa").Page("aa").WebTable("tb").GetCellData(2,1)
```

Please advise.

---

[image]

---

**Update # 1**
1

```
myvalue= Browser("aa").Page("aa").WebTable("tb").GetCellData(2,1)
```

'value returns "dsfsdf sdfsdfdsf DOB: 1/01/2015 Member ID: 8587"

2 I inspected the cell in chrome. I see this:

```
<td class="name" rowspan="1">
                                            <a href="/id/5858"><span></span></a>
                                            <h3>
                                            dsfsdf sdfsdfdsf
                                            </h3>
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td>DOB:</td>
                                                    <td>1/01/2015</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Member ID:</td>
                                                    <td>8587</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
```

3. In front end, i see the entire cell is a link but in source code you can see only one element is a link. I think they have applied css to make the cell as a link.

SHould I first go to the cell then find the link and then click on it? I researched all day but no luck. Please advise.

---

**Update # 2**

This is a dot net page.

```
set rowObject = Browser("aa").Page("aa").WebTable("tb").Object.getElementsByTagName("tr").item(1)
```

If I keep item(1) it clicks on the 2nd row as expected. index 0 is the header. index 1 is the 2nd row.

If I change to item(2), it does nothing.

If I change to item(4), it clicks 3rd row(index 2). Instead it should click 5th row (index 4).

If I change to item(5), it does nothing. Weird. So this answer is not working consistently. I think UFT is being confused way that the page was developed.

I took the html source code and then created a html file locally. Changed all anchor texts from empty to some texts:

```
            <a href="/id/5554"><span>id2</span></a>
```

Then I used your original code that you posted. It works just fine as expected for all rows.

I will reach out to dev team to see if they can add anchor text and then apply css to hide it. Most likely they wont do anything.

Also can we describe the "Link" here to "a" tag so UFT will look for "a" tag instead of link texts/anchor texts.

```
set objLink = Browser("aa").Page("aa").WebTable("tb").ChildItem(intRow, intCol, "Link",0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[childitem](http://helpfiles.intactcloud.com/QTP/11.00/QTP11-00_GeneralHelp/WebForms/WEBFORMSPACKAGELib~WbfGrid~ChildItem.html)** method of a webTable.

Try something like:

```
Dim objLink, intRow, intCol
intRow = 2
intCol = 1
set objLink = Browser("aa").Page("aa").WebTable("tb").ChildItem(intRow, intCol, "Link",0)
if objLink.exists(3) then
    objLink.Click
end if
```

**Update 2:**

Since the link present inside the webtable's cell does not have any text associated with it, UFT is not able to find it using the `ChildItem` method. This can also be verified by using the `ChildItemCount` method of the webtable. Hence, we now need to use object's native methods as shown below:

```
set rowObject = Browser("aa").Page("aa").WebTable("tb").Object.getElementsByTagName("tr").item(1)      'HERE item(1) means the 2nd item or 2nd row. It is a zero-based index, hence for 2nd row, we write index=1
set colObject = rowObject.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0)     'item(0) means 1st item or 1st column as it is a zero based index
Set collectionLinks = colObject.getElementsByTagName("a")        'getting a collection of all the links present inside cell(2,1)
collectionLinks.item(0).Click                                    'item(0) means the 1st link in the cell(2,1)
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I ran the above code multiple times yesterday. It worked.  I ran this today many times. It is not clicking at all. I am totally confused with UFT. It is not consistent sometimes. I restarted the machine. Opened the app again. Application looks just same. I am not sure what could go wrong. Nothing has changed. It should work. Now it does not. Please advise.

Comment: Just before the If statement, write `msgbox objLink.exists(2)` and run the code. Let me know what is displayed is msgbox.

Comment: It says "object required". Please see the image.

Comment: Well, it just means that the cell no more has a link inside it. Are you able to click on that link manually?

Comment: You are getting the error because the Link does not have any text assosiated with it `<a href="/id/5858"><span></span></a>`. This could would have worked correctly if the link had some text associated like: `<a href="/id/5858"><span>LinkName</span></a>`.(Notice the `LinkName`)

Comment: @bugfinder I have updated the solution. I have tested the code at my end and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But still no luck. Please see the update #2.

Comment: "Link" is the name of the class whereas  "a" is the name of a tag. The childitem method takes classname as parameter, not a tagname. Hence, we can't replace "Link" with "a".

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thanks. I talked to dev team to have text inside the "a" tag. They wont do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Subroutine.

**Note:** You should know the index value of an object you want to click. Try to use Object Spy to know the index of an item. You might not click your desired element if you set the wrong index.

```
Sub ClickWebTableIndex(BrowserPropertyName, BrowserPropertyValue, PagePropertyName, PagePropertyValue, WebTablePropertyName, WebTablePropertyValue, ChildObjectClassName, ChildObjectPropertyName, ChildObjectPropertyValue, IndexValue)

    Set oBrowser = Description.Create()
    oBrowser("micclass").Value = "Browser"
    oBrowser(BrowserPropertyName).Value = BrowserPropertyValue

    Set oPage = Description.Create()
    oPage("micclass").Value = "Page"
    oPage(PagePropertyName).Value = PagePropertyValue

    Set oWebTable = Description.Create()
    oWebTable("micclass").Value = "WebTable"
    oWebTable(WebTablePropertyName).Value = WebTablePropertyValue

    Set childObject = Description.Create
    childObject("micclass").value = ChildObjectClassName
    childObject(ChildObjectPropertyName).value = ChildObjectPropertyValue

    Browser(oBrowser).Page(oPage).WebTable(oWebTable).ChildObjects(childObject)(IndexValue).FireEvent "OnClick"

End Sub
```